# Unable to connect to localhost after installing Apache

Tags: server, apache2

I am unable to connect to localhost after installing Apache. I checked with the following URLs: `https//localhost` , `https//127.0.1.1` and  `https//127.0.1.1`

Below is the log message I received and my IP address information:

```
avinash@ubuntu:/etc/init.d$ sudo service apache2 restart
[sudo] password for avinash: 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName


avinash@ubuntu:/etc/init.d$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:54:d4:d1  
          inet addr:192.168.56.130  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe54:d4d1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17657949 (17.6 MB)  TX bytes:749463 (749.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9920 (9.9 KB)  TX bytes:9920 (9.9 KB)
```

Comment: How about `http://localhost`? Note the ':' in the URL.

Comment: Can you post the output of this command = netstat -tunlp

Answer (score 1):

try using http:// for localhost instead of https://

```
http://localhost
```

https:// is for secure servers also the default local ip address is 127.0.0.1 not 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Use the below URL:

```
http://localhost
```

Also add the below line to your **apache2.conf** file at **/etc/apache2**

```
ServerName localhost
```

The above will suppress the warning

```
waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```